# Prove Inequality that looks like Bernoulli's

Tags: inequality

I have to prove the following inequality 
$$\dfrac{n a}{1 + n a} < \sqrt[n]{a} < 1 + \dfrac{a}{n},$$
for $a > 0, n \in \mathbb N^\ast$.

I tried to start with Bernoulli's inequality without success. To me, it looks like a combination of Bernoulli's and arithmetic and geometric means inequality.

I can't see how I can combine them. Another idea would be to use induction but the constant $a$ doesn't help. Any suggestions?

Comment: For the base case you have to show that $\frac{a}{1 + a} \le \sqrt{a} \le 1 + a$ for $a > 0$. Hint: Think derivatives.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

\begin{align*}
\left(1+\dfrac{a}{n}\right)^{n}\geq 1+n\cdot\dfrac{a}{n}=1+a>a,
\end{align*}
so $1+a/n>a^{1/n}$.

\begin{align*}
\left(\dfrac{na}{1+na}\right)^{n}&=\left(\dfrac{1}{1+\dfrac{1}{na}}\right)^{n}\\
&=\dfrac{1}{\left(1+\dfrac{1}{na}\right)^{n}}\\
&\leq\dfrac{1}{1+n\cdot\dfrac{1}{na}}\\
&=\dfrac{1}{1+\dfrac{1}{a}}\\
&<\dfrac{1}{\dfrac{1}{a}}\\
&=a,
\end{align*}
so $na/(1+na)<a^{1/n}$.

Answer (score 2):

By AM-GM with $(n-1)$ ones and one $a$,
$$ \sqrt[n]{a} \leq \frac{1}{n} [(n-1)+a] \leq 1 + \frac{a}{n}. $$

Then, by letting $a' = 1/a$ you get the other inequality!